# Cannot capture the debug assertion in google test(death test doesn't satisfy it)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I create a C++ function like following

```
    int NeedTest(Pointer* b)
    {
        if(b == nullptr)
        {
            _ASSERTE(!"pointer is null.");
            return 0;
        }
        else
       {
           //do something
           return 1;
       }

    }
```

Now I want to verify that when passing a null pointer into this function, it will return 0 and the `_ASSERTE`is triggered.
However, I tried with death test for this function several times, seems like the debug assertion dialog still shows up and failed since this debug assertion is not "death", it only show up the debug assertion dialog in debug mode and when I hit "ignore", the process can continue. For this case, death test is not appropriate.

```
TEST(Mytest,test1)
{
   EXPECT_DEATH(NeedTest(nullptr), "success");

}
```

Google test is failed since it is NOT "die" and the debug assertion dialog shows up.
Is there anyway in google test that I can `EXPECT_DEBUG_ASSERTION_HAPPEN` and not show up the debug assertion dialog in google test?
I want to test that my code does contain `_ASSERTE` in debug mode.
I also tried `EXPECT_DEATH_IF_SUPPORTED`and `EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH`, none of them can depress the dialog and tell me the test is passed.

Comment: That's a personal preference, but I would advise against using assertions for this exact reason: assertion failures unlike exceptions or error codes do not have an in-language way to catch them, and they interact badly with all kinds of client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googletest's death tests cannot suppress dialogs; the test program would spawn a separate process for running the test case and analyze how it exists and what it writes to the stderr. Instead of `_ASSERTE` you can use standard C++ `assert`; on failure it does what googletest wants it to do.